# Problems with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm using preg_match as a way to validate inputs on a form.  Specifically, I am trying to validate input of currency.  Here is the function:

```
if (preg_match("/^\$(((\d{1,3},)+\d{3})|\d+)\.\d{2}$/i", $inString)) {
    return True;
} else {
    return False;
}
```

I can get this to work AT ALL.  I keeps returning False regardless of what I feed it (including valid strings). I'm sure I'm doing something obviously wrong, but I can't see it.  You know how it is...

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: can you show your `$inString` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$inString = '1550.50';

if (preg_match("/\b\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?\b/", $inString)) {
    echo "True"; 
} else {
    echo "False";
}
```

**explanation:**

```
\b      # word boundary assertion
\d{1,3} # 1-3 digits
(?:     # followed by this group...
 ,?     # an optional comma
 \d{3}  # exactly three digits
)*      # ...any number of times
(?:     # followed by this group...
 \.     # a literal dot
 \d{2}  # exactly two digits
)?      # ...zero or one times
\b      # word boundary assertion
```

Comment: That was amazingly fast, and it works perfectly now.  I obviously need to brush up on my regular expressions...  Thank you!

Comment: @SpencerX -- I voted it up for you, but be careful, my understanding is moderators disapprove asking OP to accept one's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `preg_match` function **already** returns True or False depending on whether it matches, so there is no need to return True or False a second time.

This means you can directly echo the values of True or False:

```
$inString = "$12.50";
$price_regex = '~^\$(((\d{1,3},)+\d{3})|\d+)\.\d{2}$~';
echo preg_match($price_regex, $inString);
// echoes 1
```

You can also directly return these values:

```
return preg_match($price_regex, $inString);
```

You can perform a Boolean test:

```
if( preg_match($price_regex, $inString) ) { // take some action }
else { // take another action }
```

If what you want instead is to echo some value depending on whether there is a match, do this:

```
echo (preg_match($price_regex, $inString)) ? "**It Matches!**" : "Nah... No match." ;
```

**Notes:**

- Changed the delimiter to `~` (more legible)
- Removed the `i` flag (there are no letters, so it doesn't need to be case-insensitive)

Answer (score 1):

Both answers given before this *work*, but here's an explanation of why the original preg_match pattern *didn't* work.

It's because the pattern is enclosed in double quotes. When PHP sees this, it treats whatever follows a $ sign as a variable name. If you need to include a literal $ sign inside a double quoted string, the dollar has to be preceded by a backslash.

so both of these patterns work:

`'/^\$(((\d{1,3},)+\d{3})|\d+)\.\d{2}$/i'`
`"/^\\$(((\d{1,3},)+\d{3})|\d+)\.\d{2}\$/i"`

Obviously, using single quotes is simpler in this case.

Comment: Thank you, that is also tremendously helpful!